# Caching with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I am trying to cache an expensive fragment of my view.  Other parts of the application have working caching.
This is the view (in haml)

```
@users.each do
  - cache user, expires_in: 60*60*8 do
    %tr{id: "user_id_#{user.id}"}
      %td= user.name
      # lots of other simple calcs
      -cache "user_#{user.id}_score", expires_in: 1.week do
        - score = #expensive calculation
        %td= score
```

However, when I look at production, I cannot find the cache

```
Rails.cache.read('user_215_score')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: cache key is far more complex, look how it's built: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Integration/cache_key

Comment: I'm surprised the cache key is completely different from the doc I pointed... +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Forgot to add 'views'

```
Rails.cache.read 'views/user_215_retention'
```

Returned the expected result